# Kippo graph Human Activity. What is it?

Tags: honeypot

So I was running a Kippo honeypot. In Kippo graph there is a diagram tilted "Human activity" (see attached photo). What does it mean? Does it mean that, for example, on 21-11-2014 90 real attackers tried to attack my honeypot?

Thanks.

[image: Kippo graph - Human activity]

Answer (score 1):

Kippo attempts to guess if the session was automated or a human. So the graph is a little more like "there were 90 *possibly* human attacks."